# Docker images not caching between different builds

Tags: docker

I can't seem to get my head around why these builds are not caching?

First build:

```
Step 1/12 : ARG CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION
Step 2/12 : FROM node:$CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION
 ---> 672002a50a0b
Step 3/12 : ARG BUILD_TOKEN
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d76a52dccfd9
Step 4/12 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y locales &&     sed --in-place '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //' /etc/locale.gen &&     locale-gen &&     echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile &&     echo "export TZ=UTC" >> /etc/profile
 ---> Running in 2903bfda5367
```

Second build:

```
Step 1/12 : ARG CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION
Step 2/12 : FROM node:$CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION
 ---> 672002a50a0b
Step 3/12 : ARG BUILD_TOKEN
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d76a52dccfd9
Step 4/12 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y locales &&     sed --in-place '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //' /etc/locale.gen &&     locale-gen &&     echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile &&     echo "export TZ=UTC" >> /etc/profile
 ---> Running in c76a33c7599f
```

The `BUILD_ARG` is different in every build though. Is that what is causing it to not cache? They are using the same runner every time. Apart from that everything is the same.

Afaiac, it's using the cache for the `BUILD_ARG`.

First part of my `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION

FROM node:$CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION

ARG BUILD_TOKEN

# Set locale
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    # Generate needed locale
    sed --in-place '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen && \
    # Set system locale (add line)
    echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile && \
    # Set system timezone (add line)
    echo "export TZ=UTC" >> /etc/profile

    # Install git
RUN apt-get install -y git
...
```

Answer (score 0):

docker builds are in layers. Each command in Dockerfile produces a new layer and u can see its hash. That is why you should structure your Dockerfile more logically. The problem in your Dockerfile is you are using `apt-get update`. This command save somewhere in the image some small pieces about what packages have been updated and when. This when would be some timestamp that will be different each time you run this command and that is why it generate different hash

**Solution**

Create seperate Dockerfile where you run the `apt-get update && apt-get install ...` and pre-build the image, and then for your app use this image in `FROM` command.